# Problems to detect field types using the NestJS GraphQL plugin with the Code-First approach

Tags: nestjs

Today i've upgraded a GraphQL API built with NestJS to the version 7.

I've setup the project to use the new [NestJS GraphQL Plugin with the nest-cli](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#cli-plugin) with the [code first approach](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#code-first), however i got the following error trying to map one of the classes:

`(node:67283) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot determine GraphQL output type for auth`

Here the `nest-cli.json`:

```
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "tsConfigPath": "tsconfig.json",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "@nestjs/graphql/plugin",
        "options": {
          "typeFileNameSuffix": [".model.ts", ".args.ts", ".input.ts"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And here two of the models: `login-success.model.ts`, `auth.model.ts` involved in the error:

```
// login-success.model.ts
import { ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { Auth } from './auth.model';

@ObjectType()
export class LoginSuccess {
  auth: Auth;
  // other stuffs
}
```

```
// auth.model.ts
import { Field, Int, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class Auth {
  accessToken: string;
  @Field(type => Int)
  expiresIn: number;
}
```

Anyone got the some problem ? There is something wrong in the mapping ?